Change of value according to a sine curve with a given angle
There is a formula for calculating the x-coordinate. width is the screen width, and progressAnimation changes linearly over time from 0 to 1:
val x = width * progressAnimation

The formula needs to be adjusted so that x changes not linearly, but according to a sine curve—starting slow, then faster towards the middle, and then slowing down again at the end:
val x = width * (0.5 * (1 - cos(progressAnimation * Math.PI)))

But in this case, the speed of change of x follows the sine curve from 0 to 180 degrees.
However, I need x to change over the time not according to 0..180 sine curve, but according to 30..150 sine curve
When progressAnimation==0 x should also be 0. When progressAnimation==1 then x should equal width. The change of x should match 30..150 sine curve pattern.
Could you please tell me where to place this data in my formula so that the change reflects this?

What do you mean by this line "However, I need x to change over the time not according to 0..180 sine curve, but according to 30..150 sine curve"? Did you mean at progressAnimation==0 you want change of $x$ to be $\sin(30^\circ)$ and at progressAnimation==1 you want change of $x$ to be $\sin(150^\circ)$?

And use MathJax to improve readability of your question.
